# Pros and cons of integrating ZK with JBoss Seam and not using JSF?

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam, zk

Please could someone tell me why it is better to use ZK with JBoss Seam instead of using JSF with JBoss Seam. What are the advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros of ZK + Seam: fast development cycle, easy to learn, better productivity.

Pros of JSF + Seam: default support. The power of ui objects depends on the JSF solution you choose. IMO, the most important thing for JSF to do is to define the standard set of rich widgets like Swing does. Right now, it is painful to change from one supplier to another and hard to make them work together in the same page.

Comment: zkseam could be found at http://code.google.com/p/zkseam2/. Maybe I am wrong but it seems to be done by a contributor.